# Replace sql server with RavenDB

Tags: entity-framework-4, ravendb, wcf-ria-services

I have a silverlight application that communicates with the sql server database. The server side is a WCF RIA webservices that use EF 4 for persisting data back to db.

I am considering switching to RavenDB for two reasons

1. Scalability
2. Freedom from updating schema on production server.

My questions

1. How easy it is to switch to RavenDB. Is it as easy as pointing the connection toRavenDB.
2. Will it create a schema automatically by inspecting the entities.
3. can i continue to use linq in wcf. Or do i need to replace code in it?

Thanks,
Ankur

Comment: First problem to fix is removing WCF... Second of all I don't see how you get 'scalability' out of RavenDB. Yes RavenDB is fast, and scalable, but so is SQL Server, and are you really having performance issues with SQL Server?

Comment: No, I am not having any performance issues yet. This is a new application. RavenDB was offering the benefit of becoming schemaless. Upgrades to the application would have meant only updating compiled binaries (or thats what I hope) and not having to run ALTER scripts on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. It will most likely require a model change since a model suited from RavenDB is usually very different from a relational model you're likely to be using now.
2. There is no schema with RavenDB.
3. Yes, but you'll probably need to rewrite the queries to match the new document-oriented model that you'll come up with for using RavenDB.